# How to convert windows batch file to mac sh file?

Tags: java, shell, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I was using windows batch file to execute my automation scripts through Jenkins but now I have to move to Mac OS x. Can anyone help me to convert following batch file to shell scripts?

```
java –cp C:/somepath/bin; C:/somepath/lib/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

```
java –cp <path1>:<path2> org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

if Java is not in the path you have to add it in front of the Java command

Comment: @Ramya are you shure all libraries ar in the correct path?

Comment: yes all libraries are in the path .. i got the solution it was mistake in hyphen. Thank you